# Draw two separate samples of 100 independent standard normals with rnorm?

Tags: r, distribution

In an assignment, it asks to "Draw two separate samples of 100 independent standard normals" using R. I assume that I use the rnorm function, which returns a value from a normal distribution. Given that the standard normal is the same every time, if I just use `rnorm(100, mean = 0, std = 1)` will that meet the requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try it and see???

Comment: I guess my question is about the independence. I see that it returns a vector with 100 values.

Answer (score 0):

Should be ...`sd = 1`... . And "mean = 0, sd = 1" are the defaults for `rnorm`, so this is equivalent to `rnorm(100)`. As for your class requirements, it's probably not for us to say what will satisfy them.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code

```
rnorm(100, mean = 0, std = 1)
```

will generate two separate samples of 100 independent standard normal variables. As every time we run it, it draws random numbers, which follow SN distribution, sample will be independent.

Also, you can simply use

```
rnorm(100)
```

As, if mean or sd are not specified rnorm() function assumes the default values of 0 and 1, respectively.